# LZW algorithm - binary compress

Tags: binary, compression, gzip, bzip2, lzw

I'm trying to build a program for file compressing.
so far I implemented the Huffman coding algorithm but I noticed it's not enough - the compressing is minimal, and I can compress only a few millions of bits and usually it only 1% of the original file.
I searched for information about it and I found out that most of compressing file programs like  bzip2 and gzip are using the combination of the LZW and Huffman algorithms together.
When I tried to use the LZW algorithm I got stuck about how to do it on binary, on bits. Most of the examples and explanations about this algorithm are examing on alphabetical strings and some limited-inadequately information on binary. Is there a full clear guide for how to implement it on binary or a way to understand it simplly?

Answer (score 1):

Neither uses LZW. gzip uses [LZ77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77), which finds matching strings in previous data. The literals and length/distance pairs are then sent using Huffman codes. bzip2 uses a [Burrows-Wheeler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform), followed by a move-to-front, run-length encoding, and Huffman coding.

Comment: I know those algorithms and tried again to read about them and use it on binary data and just unsuccessfully to implement it.
The LZ77 algorithm seems more effective but how can I tell jump backward in a binary code in a way it understands it as pointer and not a new "byte number" and all this without increase the size.
I don't understand it and I'll be grateful if someone can simplify it for me in a way I can implement it on files

Comment: You don't need to implement it yourself. Just use a library like [zlib](https://zlib.net/).

Comment: I don't want to because the point in here is to try to implement it by myself (the code), this is the real challenge.

Comment: Read [RFC 1951](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1951) for a description of the deflate compressed format. That will show you one example for how literals and length/distance pairs are coded, and furthermore, how the descriptions of the codes are themselves compressed.

Comment: This is a very difficult document but I will try to extract the information I need from it.
Thank you very much for all of your help.

Comment: @Black-Wolf Did you figure out how to jump backward in a binary file? I have to implement it too, so it would be great if you can share your findings. thanks